# Can anyone please identify this flower?

Tags: identification

[image]

A friend of mine is trying to identify this flower.  She describes it as three double petals almost folded and two white stamens. Black centre with a touch of yellow. Multiple flowers off one large stem with thin long leaves.

Comment: can you add another image showing the foliage as well as the flower, and preferably one showing the whole plant (if possible) as well.